# How to use integer and binary variables with matlab GA toolbox?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, integer-programming

I used matlab GA toolbox to solve an integer programming problem. The problem has some binary variables. 
I used nonlinear constraints such as `x*(1-x) = 0` for binary variables, but matlab outputs real values for these variables.

One another problem is that final solution is not feasible! I used this line of code:

```
options = gaoptimset(options,'CreationFcn', @gacreationlinearfeasible);
```

But matlab still generating no feasible solutions.

A friend suggested using inequality constraints instead of equality ones, but that failed.

Then there is two problems. 1) say matlab about binary variables, 2) generating feasible solutions.

How can I use matlab GA for my problem?

Comment: You can certainly use the integer programming solver to make use binary variables.  Simply restrict their valid range so that they're between `[0,1]` and that they are integer.  This effectively enforces the constraints to be binary.

Comment: I want to use GA toolbox, not any other solver

Comment: Why is this a constraint? Can you explain why?

Comment: I must compare solution times in 2 methods, GA and MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is best solution, but I solved my problem by substitute constraints for penalty coefficients in fitness function.

After all, as a suggestion, anyone who has same problem can try GAlib (C++ genetic library) instead of matlab.